# A todo application in React using hooks

Tags: javascript, react.js, to-do-list

I am learning React and wanted to implement a todo app using function components. Any suggestions and criticism is welcome, especially regarding best practices.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

class Todo {
  constructor(id, description, complete) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.complete = complete;
  }
}

export default () => {

  const [idCounter, setIdCounter] = useState(1);
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);
  const [todoDescription, setTodoDescription] = useState('');

  function addTodo() {
    setTodoList(
      [...todoList, new Todo(idCounter, todoDescription, false)]
    );
    setIdCounter(idCounter + 1);
    setTodoDescription('');
  }

  function markTodoItemComplete(id) {
    const todoListClone = todoList.slice();
    todoListClone[id - 1].complete = true;
    setTodoList(todoListClone);
  }

  return <>
    {todoList.map((todoItem) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={todoItem.id}>
          <span>{todoItem.id} - {todoItem.description} - {todoItem.complete ? 'Completed' : 'Waiting'}</span>
          <button
            onClick={() => markTodoItemComplete(todoItem.id)}
            disabled={todoItem.complete}>
            Mark as complete
          </button>
          <br/>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    })}
    <br/>
    <input
      onChange={e => setTodoDescription(e.target.value)}
      value={todoDescription}
    />
    <br/>
    <button
      disabled={!todoDescription}
      onClick={addTodo}>Add Todo
    </button>
  </>
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function markTodoItemComplete(id) {
    const todoListClone = todoList.slice();
    todoListClone[id - 1].complete = true;
    setTodoList(todoListClone);
  }
```

This seems me not good practice, what you could have done is just getting id(key) of array and just set it to true.
like

```
 function markTodoItemComplete(id) {
    todoListClone[id].complete = true;
  }
```

Comment: I strongly support not to clone here. Please motivate changing the index expression.

Comment: is cloning here a crime @greybeard??

Comment: (Cloning in itself is not a crime. It can be a useful tool and prevent unwanted consequences. It can introduce unwanted consequences, starting with unwarranted processing effort. Why do you ask? I was under the impression that we agree cloning in `markTodoItemComplete()` is not a good idea. I have second thought noticing that in your second code block you kept the (undeclared/undefined) name `todoListClone`.)

Comment: `todoListClone[id].complete = true;` will not update the view.